# Push Notification Onclick it should open the application

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm developing an app and use push notification. My app contains a list of IDs. Clicking on particular id, I am able to see the details related to the id.

The push notification contains an id and so I want that if I click on the push notification then it will open the details page of the id for display details related to the id from the notification.

For e.g. 
In my app, I have number of Ids (for example 123,456,657...) and if I clicking on 123, it will show the details related to the id like name, phone no, emails etc.. and my push notification contain 123, I want that if I clicked on push notification, it will open the details page of 123 id.

Comment: not clear..please explain more..

Comment: In my app i have number of Ids (for example 123,456,657...) and by clicking on 123 it will show the details of the id like name, phone no, emails etc.. and my push notification contain 123, i want clicking on push notification it will open the details page of 123 id.

Comment: So you have to pass your id through `Bundle` and get it in your activity and check if its contains that id. If it is then show detail of that particular notification details with that id.

Answer (score 0):

Using PushNotification you are passing some id for your items in application's local database or WebService calling id or whatever..

Create a pending intent for that DetailActivity and pass this id in bundle for this.. and write code to getId from bundle here and based on that get data from database or WebService..

if any query feel free to ask..

Answer (score 0):

You must put the `id` as an extra for intent associated to notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

// Create intent and set extra
Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, <YourDetailsActivity>.class);
targetIntent.putExtra("id", id);

// Associate intent to notification
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

// Create notification...
Notification notification = builder.build();

// ...and show it
NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nManager.notify(<YOUR_NOTIFICATION_ID>, notification);
```